# JAX performance problems

Tags: python, jax

I am obviously not following best practices, but maybe that's because I don't know what they are. Anyway, my goal is to generate a tubular neighborhood about a curve in three dimensions. A curve is give by an array of length three `f(t) = jnp.array([x(t), y(t), z(t)])`.

Now, first we compute the unit tangent:

```
def get_uvec2(f):
  tanvec = jacfwd(f)
  return lambda x: tanvec(x)/jnp.linalg.norm(tanvec(x))
```

Next, we compute the derivative of the tangent:

```
def get_cvec(f):
  return get_uvec2(get_uvec2(f))
```

Third, we compute the orthogonal frame at a point:

```
def get_frame(f):
  tt = get_uvec2(f)
  tt2 = get_cvec(f)
  def first2(t):
    x = tt(t)
    y = tt2(t)
    tt3 = (jnp.cross(x, y))
    return jnp.array([x, y, tt3])
  return first2
```

which we use to generate a point in the circle around a given point:

```
def get_point(frame, s):
  v1 = frame[1, :]
  v2 = frame[2, :]
  return jnp.cos(s) * v1 + jnp.sin(s) * v2
```

And now we generate the point on the tubular neighborhood corresponding to a pair of parameters:

```
def get_grid(f, eps):
  ffunc = get_frame(f)
  def grid(t, s):
    base = f(t)
    frame = ffunc(t)
    return base + eps * get_point(frame, s)
  return grid
```

And finally, we put it all together:

```
def get_reg_grid(f, num1, num2, eps):
  plist = []
  tarray = jnp.linspace(start = 0.0, stop = 1.0, num = num1)
  sarray = jnp.linspace(start = 0.0, stop = 2 * jnp.pi, num = num2)
  g = get_grid(f, eps)
  for t in tarray:
    for s in sarray:
      plist.append(g(t, s))
  return jnp.vstack(plist)
```

Finally, use it to compute the tubular neighborhood around a circle in the xy-plane:

```
f1 = lambda x: jnp.array([jnp.cos(2 * jnp.pi * x), jnp.sin(2 * jnp.pi * x), 0.0])

fff = np.array(get_reg_grid(f1, 200, 200, 0.1))
```

The good news is that it all works. The *bad* news is that this computation takes well over an hour. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Probably in you O(n²) function (get_reg_grid)

Comment: @Magaren I hope that was a joke. n^2 = 40000. This program apparently generates under ten points A SECOND.

Comment: for t in tarray...for s in sarray...not?

Comment: @Magaren Yes, what is your point?

Comment: My point is that in your function get_reg_grid the variable array is not accessible...instead of array don't you mean tarray/sarray?

Comment: @magaren A yes, that IS a good point.

Comment: @Magaren What is weird is that the code is correct, and yet the cut and paste truncatred the variable names.

Comment: performed better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAX and numpy share one key rule-of-thumb for getting good performance: **if you are writing `for` loops over array values, your code will probably be slow**.

To make your code more performant, you should replace your loops with vectorized operations. One nice feature of JAX is [`jax.vmap`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.vmap.html), a vectorizing transform which makes this relatively easy. You can also use [`jax.jit`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.jit.html) to JIT-compile your function and get even faster execution.

Here's a modified version of your `get_reg_grid` function that returns the same result with much faster execution:

```py
import jax
from functools import partial

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnames=['f', 'num1', 'num2'])
def get_reg_grid(f, num1, num2, eps):
  tarray = jnp.linspace(start = 0.0, stop = 1.0, num = num1)
  sarray = jnp.linspace(start = 0.0, stop = 2 * jnp.pi, num = num2)
  g = get_grid(f, eps)
  g = jax.vmap(g, in_axes=(None, 0))
  g = jax.vmap(g, in_axes=(0, None))
  return jnp.vstack(g(tarray, sarray))
```

With this approach, your code executes in about 300 microseconds:

```py
%timeit get_reg_grid(f1, 200, 200, 0.1).block_until_ready()
# 296 µs ± 157 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you think it is the de-looping or the jit that helped most?

Comment: Removing the loops is definitely the most important piece in terms of performance.